# On Android 11 and upper is there any way to get a persistent access on a DocumentFile Uri located on the external storage knowing its Uri?

Tags: android

It is well know it we can use Intent action **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE**, to ask user to grant permission on a user-selected directory or the  **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**, to open and get permission on a user-selected file (DocumentFile), However, in case you already well-known the file-path you are willing to **get** a **persistent access** is there any alternative to request a persistent access to this **specific DocumentFile Uri?**

(Assuming that, each file on the **public shared external storage** can always be resolved as a ExternalStorage DocumentFile thus to an DocumentFile Uri)

For now, as alternative, i just use the **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** to request the user to select the file nammed by the required $name. Unfortunatelly it is not really practice cause the user is free to select another DocumentFile that is not the required one.

Answer (score 0):

> However, in case you already well-known the file-path you are willing to get a persistent access is there any alternative to request a persistent access to this specific DocumentFile Uri?

No, but the question makes little sense. If you already have read access to the content directly via the filesystem, you do not need to request persistent access, because you already have it. If you do not already have read access to the content directly via the filesystem, asking for persistent access would be pointless. Asking for persistent access only makes sense when you *do not* have direct filesystem access, but instead are working with the results of a Storage Access Framework request (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`).

> the user is free to select another DocumentFile that is not the required one.

There is no concept as "the required one". It is the user's phone and the user's content. The user can do whatever the user wants.

Comment: Yes, I perfectly understand your point.
In my case, for example when an content from a third-party app (for example a FileExplorer) the content is generally resolved either through a FileProvider or a DocumentProvider; in both case it is almost always possible to retrieve either the filePath (FileProvider) or the DocumentId(DocumentProvider)  using some contentProvider query mechanisms. Also, in most case there is way to get a DocumentId from a filePath or a FilePath from a DocumentId.
Now i have the file path, i want to request a persistent access on the resource through SAF.

Comment: @ToukeaTatsi: Again, either you have filesystem access, or you do not. If you do have filesystem access, it is already persistent. If you do not have filesystem access, you cannot get filesystem access. For example, regarding "it is almost always possible to retrieve either the filePath (FileProvider)", frequently you will not have filesystem access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Please consider the following information:
I don't have fileSystem access, I use only SAF since 1 November.
However, I have codded mechanisms that allow me to resolve any FileProvider or DocumentProvider Uri into either a FilePath (for user information purposes) or to ExternalDocumentUri for feature purposes! When a third-party app Uri is opened, my app can try to resolve it to an ExternalStorageUri I already have permission on or fail. In case of success, the app prefers the persistedUri in case of failure, it opens the submitted URI but can't EDIT (my issue)

Comment: @ToukeaTatsi: You can only request persistable permission for a `Uri` that your app obtains directly from the Storage Access Framework. If you get a `Uri` by any other mechanism, you cannot request persistable access.

Comment: Thanks to help. Sure, maybe it is just not yet possible using the current API. But I am looking for alternatives.
Indeed, some third-party apps give write access permission on their provided Uri but some others not. Unfortunately, the one that was mostly used by users with my app (Analytics) doesn't give the write permission to the Uri it provides (Uri of file located on External Storage File)
Have you any idea that could help me or any alternative you may know to solve my problem?
Assuming that I am able to get a well-formed ExternalStorageUri but I dont own permission on it but I want to!

Comment: @ToukeaTatsi: "Assuming that I am able to get a well-formed ExternalStorageUri but I dont own permission on it but I want to!" -- if that were possible, that would represent a substantial security flaw.

Comment: It is possible and it is not a security issue cause having a well-formed Uri doesn't means you can access the resource behind (The real security is at this point).
Nevertheless, I ensure you that it is possible and it is what I do in my case.
However, for now when the user wants to edit the opened file, I prompt him with the file picker with a message like "select the file named "$filename"" and the initial_uri for the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, is the document parent tree. Not really user-friendly, but it is the best I can. Previously with filesystem permission it was more simple!

Comment: @ToukeaTatsi: "having a well-formed Uri doesn't means you can access the resource behind (The real security is at this point)" -- you asked to be able to bypass the real security ("but I dont own permission on it but I want to!").

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your previous post correctly (not English native): Sure, it may be an issue to get edit access on any Uri without user consent (I agree with you). What I was looking for was indeed a user-friendly and secured mechanism to request such persistent or write access permission. Maybe, I think, Google should think about adding such a mechanism to request  write access or persistent permission on a specific Uri (I think they did something similar for the MediaStore, being able to request write access for a specific MEDIA file through an UI)

Comment: A mechanism similar to the one implemented with the MediaStore.createWriteRequest()
It allows to request and get write access to specific file (MediaStoreUri)
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#manage-groups-files

Comment: The Google video for a fast overview about the explanation of the specific File access request implemented for MediaStore is available on this Google video: https://youtu.be/RjyYCUW-9tY?t=435